# How to exclude ISEQ$$ values from a Database Diff in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper, diff

Using the Database Diff tool in Oracle SQL Developer is flagging every table as changed due to the ISEQ$$ values. Is there a way to tell the diff to ignore ISEQ$$ values?

For example, I would not want to see this table in the diff results since the only difference between them is the ISEQ$$ value which is unimportant:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way.

We need to have this feature enhanced in EM, the Database, and SQL Developer.